# How are productions called that solve the pooling problem

Tags: mathematical-economics

A well known mathematical optimization problem is called the pooling problem (see here [pooling problem](https://nekst-online.nl/what-is-the-pooling-problem/))

It has many application for example in oil production, food, chemical processes. Basically you are mixing stuff from nature, which comes in different qualities and require that the final product has a certain quality.
What is a common name for these type of productions?

It is different from something like automative production where you assemeble parts.
My first thought was something like "mixing/blending" production. 
But is there a estabilshed name for this?